# Can a WPF Label be configured to focus the next item in the tab order when the access key is pressed?

Tags: .net, wpf

In WinForms, the control focused when a label's access key is pressed is determined by the tab order. Since one has to get the tab order right anyway, the label targets were essentially "effort-free" in WinForms.

It's quite a bit more effort on WPF: each and every Label's Target must be painstakingly specified by name. It can't even be clicked on the form preview (at least not within Visual Studio 2010 - I don't know about Expression).

Can this be simplified or even completely automated, like it was in WinForms?

Answer (score 1):

[Source: MS Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/vswpfdesigner/thread/38a7953e-6cff-40a6-abc9-8fa0f2a6f9a9)

Seems like this one missed the release bus this time. So you need to manually set the properties on the UI elements for now.

Update: Seems like I'm confused as to your exact question.

1. If it is about setting the keyboard navigation order for an entire form quickly, then the [KeyboardNavigation class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx#Keyboard_Navigation) is what you should be after. There is no designer support as of now.
2. If it is hookup a label with a corresponding control, such that pressing an accelerator key moves focus to the control - then you need to manually set the Label's target property. Even in Winforms, I think you had to go and modify each label to specify the exact character/accelerator. (The _ or & character before the mnemonic)

Comment: That's not quite what I'm after. My tab order is already correct.

Comment: @romkyns - like the forum post says, the designer feature to specify the tab order by clicking on the controls in design-mode was left out due to schedule constraints.

Comment: Like I say, I don't need that feature :) Even if it was already in VS2010, my question would still stand.

Comment: @romkyns - how would you want it to be ?

Comment: @Gishu: The question is about the behaviour in response to an access key (mnemonic, shortcut, whatever you wanna call it). What part of the question is unclear?

Comment: @Gishu: No, in WinForms you didn't have to specify anything. Just say "&Username" and when the user presses Alt+U the next control in the current tab order was automatically focused since the Label itself couldn't be focused. In WPF, you need to explicitly specify the target for every Label by name, and you need to define a name for each target (because they don't usually need names). romkyns (and I) are asking whether this "automatically focus the next focusable control" thing is available in WPF as well...

Comment: ... But it doesn't seem to be the case. Nobody else has answered and I didn't find anything in a web search.